# How to move caption to top in lyx

Tags: floats, lyx, indexing

In the paper, I want to show two figures in a float. So I have inserted two floats into a float. The result looks like the one on left. Here I want to write the caption together. How can I move the index to the top, as shown on the right side?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example .lyx file of what you tried? See here for more information: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Since I use Lyx(with UI interface), I do not have a code. In lyx, Step1: insert> Float>Figure. Step2: (In the float created by step1), insert> Float>Figure (do this twice so that we can attach two figure). Step3: in each subfloat,insert> Graphics

Comment: OK I can reproduce. For future reference, the link I gave is specifically for a .lyx file. A .lyx file is just a text file so you can still post a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass the option `position=top` to the subfig package. Since LyX loads this package automatically when you create subfigures, you can add the option to the already loaded package in the LaTeX preamble with `\PassOptionsToPackage` command. Here are the steps:

1. In Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble put the following code: `\PassOptionsToPackage{position=top}{subfig}`
2. Click the "OK" button.

Comment: An extended question is how to set it to the top-left? (exactly as that in picture I uploaded)

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe check out the "justification" option in the subfig documentation: http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf

Comment: Another solution: the `floatrow` package has tools for that (using the `subfloatrow` environment).